# Как словить ошибку и вместо нее бросить кастомную?

Tags: java, исключения

Есть такая переменная, куда вводятся числа.

```
Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in)
int number = cin.nextInt();
```

Если я введу букву, то словлю `InputMismatchException`. Я хочу словить эту ошибку через try/catch и вместо нее бросить собственную ошибку `CustomException`. Я знаю как ловить ошибку, но не понимаю, как ее заменить. Как это можно реализовать ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java поддерживает возможность оборачивать исключения так чтобы можно было "менять" их тип при передаче вверх по стеку ([chained exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/chained.html)). В примере ниже использован [конструктор](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html#Exception(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable)) класса Exception, который оборачивает одно исключение в другое (ищите строку с `super`):

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WrapException {
    public static class CustomException extends Exception {
        public CustomException(String message, Throwable cause) {
            super(message, cause);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception  {
        Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            cin.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            throw new CustomException("custom exception", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Строка `Caused by: ...` обозначает что одно исключение порождено другим исключением. Java позволяет создавать матрешки из исключений.

> ```
> $ javac WrapException.java
>
> $ echo 42 | java WrapException 
>
> $ echo a | java WrapException 
> Exception in thread "main" WrapException$CustomException: custom exception
>   at WrapException.main(WrapException.java:16)
> Caused by: java.util.InputMismatchException
>   at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
>   at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
>   at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
>   at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
>   at WrapException.main(WrapException.java:14)
> ```

Comment: Не позволяет. Требует, что бы я обработал `throw new CustomException` внутри блока catch. То есть, еще один try/catch писать

Comment: ... или наследуйтесь от `RuntimeException`.

Comment: Зачем вы изначально хотели менять тип исключения?

Comment: Пробую возможности

Comment: Да, наследование от `RuntimeException` помогло, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in)
int number = -1;

try { number  = cin.nextInt(); } catch(Exception e) { throw new CustomException() }
```